# Android: How to add values in Firebase database without triggering Listeners?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, event-listener

I am using `setValue()` to update a value in my Firebase database, whenever its status changes. But updating that value at constant basis, is triggering `eventListeners` that are not needed to.

Is there any way to update a value on Firebase database without triggering the other eventListeners that are not intended to be triggered?

Here's the code for setting up the value:

```java
stamp = isOnline();

        final DatabaseReference rRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final DatabaseReference uref = rRef.child("users");
        final DatabaseReference sRef = uref.child(mAuth.getUid());

        sRef.child("online_status").setValue(stamp);
```

The listener that's getting triggered (which I don't want to):

```java
uRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                ms = dataSnapshot.child("rec_msg").getValue(String.class);
                fUid = dataSnapshot.child("fromUID").getValue(String.class);
                st = dataSnapshot.child("rec_secret").getValue(String.class);
                boolean tell = dataSnapshot.child("online_status").getValue(Boolean.class);
                if(tell)
                    setTitle(hName + " (online)");
                int km = 0;
                try {
                    km = Integer.parseInt(st);
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Log.d("NumberError:", "Can't convert");
                }

                if(ms!=null && !ms.equals(""))
                    addMessageBox(ms,km);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                ms = dataSnapshot.child("rec_msg").getValue(String.class);
                fUid = dataSnapshot.child("fromUID").getValue(String.class);
                st = dataSnapshot.child("rec_secret").getValue(String.class);

                boolean tell = dataSnapshot.child("online_status").getValue(Boolean.class);
                if(tell)
                    setTitle(hName + " (online)");

                int km = 0;
                try {
                    km = Integer.parseInt(st);
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Log.d("NumberError:", "Can't convert");
                }


                if(ms!=null && !ms.equals(""))
                    addMessageBox(ms,km);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(Main5Activity.this,"User left the conversation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example and show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set/update a value of property in Firebase real-time database, there is no need to use a listener. Listeners are used to read data and **not** to write or update data. You can simply use `setValue()` or `updateChildren()` method directly on the reference like this:

```
yourRef.setValue(yourObject);
```

More details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#setValue(java.lang.Object)).

> Set the data at this location to the given value.

or

```
yourRed.updateChildren(yourMap);
```

More details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#updateChildren(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)).

> Update the specific child keys to the specified values.

**Edit:**

> How to add values in Firebase database without triggering Listeners?

As long as you have added a listener on a propery that is constantly changing, you'll always be notified about the change because this is how listeners work. If you want to add a value without having the listeners triggered, then you should not attach them to that particular reference. You cannot add a listener that is constantly looking for changes and expect it to not be triggered.

Comment: I didn't mean to convey what you got, excuse me for that. I have edited the question and also added codes for help.

Comment: I understand. In this case, please see the **edit* from my updated answer.